# Is there a way to "nice" a method of a Python script

Tags: python, linux, scheduling, nice

My scripts have multiple components, and only some pieces need to be `nice`-d. i.e., run in low priority.

Is there a way to `nice` only one method of Python, or I need to break it down into several processes?

I am using Linux, if that matters.

Comment: Process priority is managed by the OS, so I'm pretty sure you'd either have to use `subprocess` or do some sort of system where your script finds its own process and changes its priority dynamically.  Of course, the better question to ask is if any parts really need to run at high priority, or you could just run the whole thing at low priority.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a decorator that renices the running process on entry and exit:

```
import os
import functools

def low_priority(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def reniced(*args, **kwargs):
        os.nice(5)
        try:
            f(*args,**kwargs)
        finally:
            os.nice(-5)
    return reniced
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
@low_priority
def test():
    pass # Or whatever you want to do.
```

Disclaimers:

1. Works on my machine, not sure how universal os.nice is.
2. As noted below, whether it works or not may depend on your os/distribution, or on being root.
3. Nice is on a per-process basis. Behaviour with multiple threads per process will likely not be sane, and may crash.

Comment: This only works as root. Normal users are not allowed to un-nice a process, even if they were the ones to nice it.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm not sure that's true, I'm running it right now and it seems to work just fine. Arch linux, non root. Maybe it's a distribution dependent thing?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Perhaps you somehow acquired CAP_SYS_NICE? does `sudo -u nobody python -c 'import os; os.nice(5); os.nice(-5);'` work?

Comment: Yep. No clue why it's different here. Doing the opposite (lower, then raise) does cause an exception.